# How can I view all device names on LAN?

Tags: nmap, lan

I am trying to scan my local network and return a list of all connected devices with there IP, MAC Address & device name.

By device name, I mean my iPhone should say 'Jamies-iPhone' as it would when I check my routers admin application for connected devices.

At the moment I have got as far as getting the IP and MAC using:

```
sudo nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -sP > file1.txt
```

It gives me the below output into the file 'file1.txt'

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-01 18:37 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
MAC Address: 8C:34:FD:E2:E6:48 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.3
Host is up (0.0038s latency).
MAC Address: 70:56:82:C6:BE:EE (Apple)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
Host is up (0.18s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 6.42 seconds
```

I can not find any information about how to get the device name to show up, it just says 'Apple'. I specifically want to see the name of my apple TV's as I have a few and would like to be able to differentiate between them.

Comment: This is more of a `dns` setting, rather than `nmap`.  `nmap` does what it is supposed to.  So if for example you'd map these IP addresses to hostnames in e.g `/etc/hosts`  nmap would show those friendly names followed by the IP addresses.

Comment: `sudo nmap -sn IP_BASE/24` shows manufacturer name

Answer (score 1):

While `nmap` can be used to discover networked devices, the current output you have given only shows the MAC address. `nmap` has a table of MAC prefixes with their vendor and that is the reason why Apple shows up. You need to perform fingerprint tests (`-sV`) to see more details, if any or use other tools like `mdns-scan` or `mzclient` to detect the Apple TVs.

Comment: or `avahi-browse -a` if you have that command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [smb-os-discovery](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-os-discovery.html) script:

> Attempts to determine the operating system, computer name, domain, workgroup, and current time over the SMB protocol (ports 445 or 139). This is done by starting a session with the anonymous account (or with a proper user account, if one is given; it likely doesn't make a difference); in response to a session starting, the server will send back all this information.
>
> The following fields may be included in the output, depending on the circumstances (e.g. the workgroup name is mutually exclusive with domain and forest names) and the information available:
>
> - OS
>
>   - Computer name
>   - Domain name
>   - Forest name
>   - FQDN
>   - NetBIOS computer name
>   - NetBIOS domain name
>   - Workgroup
>   - System time

Example Usage

```
wget http://nmap.org/svn/scripts/smb-os-discovery.nse

nmap --script smb-os-discovery.nse -p445 192.168.1.0/24
sudo nmap -sU -sS --script smb-os-discovery.nse -p U:137,T:139 192.168.1.0/24
```

Alternative methode: Using the Address Resolution Protocol [`arp`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arp)

The command `arp -a` will display all hostnames in your LAN Network

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this seems to only return the information I need for the script host, not the other devices connected to the LAN. I ran `sudo nmap -sU -sS --script smb-os-discovery.nse -p U:137,T:139 192.168.1.*` which returned computer name for the linux machine I ran it from but not for the other results